# NASM printing product of two integers

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to multiply two integers and then converting them to ascii and then printing. The code compiles fine and no errors are given but nothing shows on screen.

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    ;to print a number after multiplication
    mov eax, x
    mov ebx, y
    MUL ebx

    ADD eax, '0' ;convert product to ascii
    mov [mynum], eax
    
    mov     ecx, mynum
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80
    
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data
    x dd 2
    y dd 3

segment .bss
    mynum resd 1
```

Thank you for helping!

EDIT: When I remove the interrupt on line 10, a zero is now printed to the terminal

Comment: What do you expect these various `int 0x80` instructions to do?  This instruction performs a system call, but I don't really see what system calls you attempt to perform.  Perhaps [edit] your post and comment each instruction with what you expect it to do.

Comment: @fuz After re-reading the code, to my understanding the ```int 0x80``` on lines 10 and 14 are useless since we are not calling a specific system call like the write or exit call. That's why we would need them on lines 20 and 24. I have deleted the two useless ones.

Comment: They are not just useless, they like cause the problem you observe.  Every `int 0x80` instruction does a system call.   But if you haven't set up to do a system call, the results will be hard to predict and may cause a crash.  So don't just sprinkle `int 0x80` in your code whenever you feel like it.

Comment: The remaining problem is that `mov eax, x` and `mov `ebx, y` load the addresses of the labels into `eax` and `ebx`.  You're missing two pairs of brackets.

Comment: Single-step your code in a debugger to see what values are in registers.  And use `strace ./a.out` to see what system calls you make.  Your simple int->ASCII conversion only works for single-digit numbers, so there's no point telling `write` to copy 4 bytes to stdout.  You're outputting 3 bytes of binary zeros, as you could see if you pipe into `hexdump -C` or use `strace`.  Also, if you don't want the high half of the product (in EDX), you should just use `imul eax, [y]`

Comment: Yep, I did not fully understand the purpose of ```int 0x80``` so thank you. And yes adding the brackets fix my code because I multiply the actual value instead of the address. Thank you fuz.